# azure bot deployment issue (echo bot)

Tags: azure, echo, serverless, azure-bot-service

I'm having some deployment issue that results in the following error, anyone can help to take a look?

```
  \> \build.cmd

  Restore completed in 1.05 sec for D:\home\site\wwwroot\EchoBot.csproj.
  Bots\EchoBot.cs(62,10): error CS1513: } expected [D:\home\site\wwwroot\EchoBot.csproj]
  Failed exitCode=1, command=dotnet publish "EchoBot.csproj" --output 
  "D:\local\Temp\___deployTemp10152" --configuration Release
  An error has occurred during web site deployment.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the error you posted above, seems to be compile issue.

a closing curly brace **`(})`** that was not found. Check the particular line in EchoBot.cs